# What is the best practice for designing apps for 320px wide?

Tags: ios, responsive-design, best-practice, typography

I'm worried about my content placement on narrow screens.

Should I shrink my fontsize for iPhone SE, for example? Specially when iOS keyboard is so big on 320px small screens.

My layout in Figma is responsive with autolayouts. But if I shrink width to 320px my typography is too big for that size of a phone. The user will have to scroll down to find text field to enter the code, for example.

Do big companies shrink font size also for 320px?

Answer (score 1):

Before proceeding with managing and resizing text for 320px screens, it's important to understand why you want to reduce the size. Consider what other information you want to display when the keyboard appears, and how important that information is to the user while they are typing. Will the text still be clearly visible even after it has been reduced in size?

When users interact with a mobile device, they are typically 1-3 feet away from the screen, whereas with a TV, they are typically 10 feet away or more. Therefore, having the same font size on all devices doesn't make sense for your users. Applying relative sizing to the font will be crucial.

[image: Bad text size]

[image: Good text size]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the app on SE or smaller devices? Shrinking font size can lead to different problems like increased difficulty to select, read, and type. It's highly recommended to run on a physical device (or better yet test with users). [Follow font guideline from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/foundations/typography/#specifications)

As for accessing the input field, you can try re-ordering the form fields so important ones are more on the top, if that's not possible, consider adding an arrow pointing down or a scroll bar to indicate overflowing fields.